# How do i make continuous player movement in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've been watching a pygame tutorial on youtube on player movement, and by using this code below, the guy making the video was able to hold down a key and the character would keep moving, but when i hold down a key the character will move once and then stop. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Code:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption("huge honkabonkaros")

x = 50
y = 440
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5

    run = True
    while run:
    pygame.time.delay(50)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            x -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            x += vel
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            y -= vel
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            y += vel

        win.fill((0, 0, 0))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pygame moving objects while pressing key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536362/pygame-moving-objects-while-pressing-key)

Comment: `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()` and the following lines should not be in your event loop but in the outer `while` loop.  -- Also, please make sure that your code is indented correctly when you post it here (select the code and press Ctrl+K to indent it once).

Comment: @skrx oh ok thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The continuous movement must be in the application loop and not in the event loop. The application loop runs once per frame, but the event loop only runs once per event. When a key is pressed a `KEYDOWN` event occurs and when a key is released a `KEYUP` event occurs, but there is no event when a key is held down:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption("huge honkabonkaros")

x = 50
y = 440
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5

    run = True
    while run:
    pygame.time.delay(50)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # INDENTATION

    #<--|

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        x -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        x += vel
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y -= vel
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        y += vel

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
```